# In 3-phase motor control, what are the physical meanings of the `d` and `q` axes?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, three-phase

The axes have interesting properties, such as the fact that in low saliency permanent magnet motors (outrunners are common examples of this) only the current in the q-axis creates torque. But the current in the d-axis can be used to change the field strength.

Is there a physical/mechanical interpretation of these axes?

Would it be fair to say that the q-axis is the axis which is most out of phase with the motor's magnetic orientation, and thus it has the most torque drive? And equivalently, d-axis current is the most in phase with the motor's magnetic field and thus it does nothing to drive the motor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The physical interpretation in terms of magnetic flux is that the d-axis is aligned with the permanent magnet field and the q-axis is aligned with the rotating stator field. If the two are aligned with each other the force is in the direction to pull the rotor towards the stator rather than to produce torque. For torque to be produced, there must be an angle between the d-axis and the q-axis. That is called the torque angle. The maximum torque is produced when the torque angle is 90 degrees. That is 90 degrees of rotation in a 2-pole motor or half way between two poles for a motor with more than 2 poles. Also called 90 electrical degrees.

Comment: "If the two are aligned with each other the force is in the direction to pull the rotor towards the stator rather than to produce torque." Is this a uniform compressive force, like a hoop stress which sucks the walls of the rotor toward the walls of the stator? Or is this a linear force which acts radially on the motor, causing the magnets on one side to get closer and on the other to get farther apart?

Comment: It is a uniform compressive force.

Comment: So negative `id` current would be a uniform expansive force, then?

Comment: I would say that a 180 degree torque angle would indicate a uniform expansive force.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. Any chance you have some imagery to go with the explanation?

Comment: I will look for imagery.

Answer (score 1):

The most closer interpretation would be a brush DC permanent magnet motor, or a separately excited brush DC motor.

Yet better model would be a separately excited DC machine with a permanent magnet.

[image]

Where armature (va, ia, La, Ra) is the q-axis. Meanwhile the field is the d-axis. In case of PM there is no field winding, the excitation is due to PM.

Stator current is \$I_s=\sqrt{I_q^2+I_d^2}\$. In the PM machine, the Id shall be zero, except in some cases it is set to be even negative - we call this "field weakening". The negative Id causes an opposed field to the PM, thus weakening.

Note that q and d axes (armature & excitation) are right angled.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing this. I can read the math of the system dynamics, but I don't understand why that math arises.

Comment: there is no natural reason for the math to arise, it transforms a three phase system into a stationary  two phase system that rotates with the reference of the synchronous motor.

only reason to do this is to simplify calculations in the system

Comment: Usually, these transformations capture some important essence of the underlying physical system. Since the transformation is intimately tied to \omega, I'd be surprised if there's also not some physical explanation for why the d-axis alone contributes to torque in a low-saliency motor.

Comment: @KennSebesta There are various types of machines. The d,q axis is a universal way to describe the machine parameters, after it has been transformed in the d,q coordinate system. BLDC and PMSM optimally would have zero salience, while the reluctance machine RM is very different. Yet, induction machine needs Id since it has no PM,...many different machines described as DC brush motor (dq).